# how to declare JFrame buttons with a table

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jbutton

I created a Class that extends from `JFrame` which has a table of buttons. In the class constructor I added the buttons to the panel but when I run the main nothing happens and I see only an empty frame. So can you hep me to find the problem?
This is the code:

```
public class Tita extends JFrame {
    JButton ff[][] = new JButton[3][3];
    int i = 0, j = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        Tita oo = new Tita();
    }

    public Tita() {
        super("Newframe"); 
        setVisible(true);
        for(i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for(j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                ff[i][j].setText("sss");
                this.getContentPane().add(ff[i][i]);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Put `setVisible()` at the end after you add your buttons.

Comment: do you mean I have to modifiy line 11 to:
this.getContentPane().add(ff[i][i]).setVisible(true);
??

Comment: Just take the line `setVisible(true);`, remove it, and put it after your for loop.

Comment: You've not initialized your buttons; they're all `null`.  As a result, you get a `NullPointerException` when you try to invoke `setText` on them.  You must create your buttons before you can use them.  On top of that, you try to add `add(ff[i][i])` rather than `add(ff[i][j])`.  Beyond those notable issues, your buttons won't appear in a table layout because the default FlowLayout won't organize them in such a manner.  Look into a suitable layout manager in addition to some basic swing example in order to understand where to go from here.

Comment: Okay thanks Vulacn I will make a search

Answer (score 1):

What is happening is that you haven't initialized any `JButton`, also, when you add the button you have `getContentPane().add(ff[i][i]);`, when it should be `getContentPane().add(ff[i][j]);`

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;



public class Tita extends JFrame {
    JButton ff[][] = new JButton[3][3];
    int i = 0, j = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        Tita oo = new Tita();
    }

    public Tita() {
        super("Newframe"); 
        setVisible(true);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setSize(new Dimension(300, 400));
        setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 0));
        for(i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for(j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                ff[i][j] = new JButton("SSS");
                ff[i][j].setSize(30, 10);
                getContentPane().add(ff[i][j],i);
            }
        }
    }
}
```